# Filter (Triple) Nested Collection using Linq C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I need to filter a List of collections > Repos > Workflows and return the result in the same format

Hopefully the [example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2IivUp) is fairly clear please shout if you think it needs more detail.

```
    // All classes have a property 'Name'
    // Filter along the branch for any that match and return only the matching items

    List<Collection> AllCollections = new List<Collection>();
    Collection CollectionA = new Collection();
    Collection CollectionB = new Collection();
    CollectionA.Repos = new List<Repo>{new Repo{Name = "FirstRepo", Workflows = new List<Workflow>{new Workflow{Name = "CI-CD"}, new Workflow{Name = "Tests"}, new Workflow{Name = "First-Ops"}}}, new Repo{Name = "SecondRepo", Workflows = new List<Workflow>{new Workflow{Name = "CI-CD"}, new Workflow{Name = "Testing"}, new Workflow{Name = "Second-Ops"}}}, new Repo{Name = "ThirdRepo", Workflows = new List<Workflow>{new Workflow{Name = "CI-CD"}, new Workflow{Name = "Testers"}, new Workflow{Name = "Third-Ops"}}}};
    CollectionB.Repos = new List<Repo>{new Repo{Name = "FronEndUI", Workflows = new List<Workflow>{new Workflow{Name = "CD"}, new Workflow{Name = "UI-Tests"}, new Workflow{Name = "first-Op"}}}, new Repo{Name = "API", Workflows = new List<Workflow>{new Workflow{Name = "CI"}, new Workflow{Name = "Testing"}, new Workflow{Name = "second-Op"}}}, new Repo{Name = "VisualBasic", Workflows = new List<Workflow>{new Workflow{Name = "Deploy"}, new Workflow{Name = "Copy"}, new Workflow{Name = "third-Op"}}}};
    AllCollections.Add(CollectionA);
    AllCollections.Add(CollectionB);
    // Filter 
    string FilterString = "";  // string FilterString = "Copy" , should return  AllCollections > CollectionB > Repo VisualBasic > Workflow Deploy
    // Result should be List of collections > List of Repos > List of workflows
    List<Collection> result = AllCollections.SelectMany(c => c.Repos.Where(r => r.Name.Contains(FilterString.ToLower())).ToList().SelectMany(w => w.Workflows.Where(w => w.Name.Contains(FilterString)))).ToList();
    // Dont know how to show nested list in a table sorry
    // This is returning the workflows but not the parent Repo and Repo's Parent, The Collection



public class Collection
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Repo> Repos { get; set; }
}

public class Repo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Workflow> Workflows { get; set; }
}

public class Workflow
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

See it here [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2IivUp)

Comment: Is `FilterString` supposed to filter only workflows? Or repos and collections as well? Also your naming in general could use some work, there's literally a standard class named `Collection` from which 99% of all .Net collections are derived from, are you sure it's wise to also write your own completely different `Collection` class?

Comment: @Blindy it's filter on Repos & Collections as well, i was thinking calling it Collection is bad idea, now i'll be changing it to MyCollection or similar...

Comment: What is the type of `result`?

Comment: @DotNetDeveloper result should be a List of Collection just as AllCollections is

Comment: @DotNetDeveloper question updated thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Example is not fairly clear. Please give example, for what FilterString what you must get? Explain precisely.

Comment: I'm not  sure what you mean FilterString is like a search it could be anything ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using [this particular overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-selectmany-3(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-1))))-system-func((-0-1-2)))).

"Projects each element of a sequence to an IEnumerable, flattens the resulting sequences into one sequence, and invokes a result selector function on each element therein."

```
var result =
   AllCollections
       .SelectMany(collection => collection.Repos,
           (collection, repo) => new {collection, repo})
       .SelectMany(collectionAndRepo => collectionAndRepo.repo.Workflows,
           (collectionAndRepo, workflow) => new {collectionAndRepo, workflow})
       .Where(collectionAndRepoAndWorkflow =>
           collectionAndRepoAndWorkflow.collectionAndRepo.collection.Name
               .Contains(FilterString)
           || collectionAndRepoAndWorkflow.collectionAndRepo.repo.Name.Contains(
               FilterString)
           || collectionAndRepoAndWorkflow.workflow.Name.Contains(FilterString))
       .GroupBy(crw => crw.collectionAndRepo.collection.Name,
           (collectionName, repoAndWorkflow) =>
               new Collection
               {
                   Name = collectionName,
                   Repos = repoAndWorkflow.GroupBy(
                       rw => rw.collectionAndRepo.repo.Name,
                       (repoName, workflows) => new Repo()
                       {
                           Name = repoName,
                           Workflows = workflows.Select(w => new Workflow()
                               {Name = w.workflow.Name}).ToList()
                       }).ToList()
               }).ToList();
```

[image]

Comment: looks pretty neat, the filter needs to work on Repos or Collection Name (thanks for pointing out I missed the name), how do i add the where clauses ? updated fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/OjXoyl

Comment: if name matches in Repo, do you want all Workflows for that repo?

Comment: §.Where(collectionAndRepoAndWorkflow => collectionAndRepoAndWorkflow.workflow.Name.Contains(FilterString)
|| collectionAndRepoAndWorkflow.repo.Name.Contains(FilterString)
|| collectionAndRepoAndWorkflow.collection.Name.Contains(FilterString))

Comment: the part of code  after comment '// convert the flattened structure back to original hierarchy' would be replaced with groupby(), I think once for each hierarchy level. I have stepped away from my dev machine, but let me know if that is not easily solved and I can try to scribble when I login next

Comment: if name matches in Repo, do you want all Workflows for that repo? yes , thanks for the rest I'll try n get it working back in a mo

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0aLUaX , works for 'Copy' but if i search for 'Visual' it returns 3 collections, close, but i think i messed it up, i'll keep trying and will update if i get further, thanks for your help

Comment: @fuzzybear does that work for you? I have updated my answer with `groupby`.